# Function changing value in calling function without return in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm learning .Net core and find some interesting code where a function changing value in calling function without return type .Anyone please explain this concept.when i tried to change value of variable li in swap it doesn't reflected in ReverseWord function

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {

        char[] chars = "ABCDEFGH".ToCharArray();
        ReverseWord(chars, 0, chars.Length - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(new string(chars));

    }
static void ReverseWord(char[] chars, int li, int hi) {
        while (li++ < hi--)
        {              
            Swap(chars, li, hi);
        }
}

private static void Swap(char[] chars, int li, int hi) {
        char temp = chars[li];
        chars[li] = chars[hi];
        chars[hi] = temp;

    }
```

Comment: You aren't changing the value of `li` in `Swap`... you're just changing the content of `chars`. If you *did* change the value of `li` in `Swap`, that wouldn't affect the calling code because it's a *value parameter*: the value of the argument in `ReverseWord` is *copied* as the initial value of the parameter in `Swap`.

Comment: Pretty much what Daisy Shipton said, li is int so it's a value type and only value is passed to Swap function, meanwhile chars is reference to array of characters. If you wish to be able to change variable li in Swap function, then you have threat it like a reference, you can do so by adding "ref" keyword to your parameter, but using it is usually a sign of bad design.

Comment: okay .so int type is value type and chars type is reference type by default

Comment: @DaisyShipton Sr, I don't really understand your answer. In fact, array of char is a reference type. So the method swap must work. This code works : https://dotnetfiddle.net/H7zPXD

Comment: @ThierryV: The OP didn't talk about changing the value of `chars`, they talked about changing the value of `li`. And even though `char[]` is a reference type, the argument is still passed by value. That value is a reference. That's not the same as pass-by-reference semantics.

Comment: @Midhul: You should separate out "pass by reference" from "reference type". They're related but separate concepts. `chars` is passed by value too, which means if you wrote `chars = null;` (for example) in `Swap`, that wouldn't change the value of `chars` in `ReverseWord`